# How do I search for a string in an list, using a tokenized list as the query's base?

Tags: python

I have a program that analyzes text for Bible verses. I have a dict that because of the brevity, I will use this as an example:

```
{
    "song": ["Song of Songs", "Song of Solomon"],
    "exod": ["Bilowgii", "Zanafilla", "1 Moseboken","Exodus", "2 Mosebog", "2 Mose", "Shemot", "2 Mooseksen", "Exode", "Esodo"]
}
```

Additionally, I have another tokenized list of a message which I have to seek if there is a book in the message (again another example).

```
`["my", "favorite", "verse", "is", "Song", "of", "Solomon", "1:2", "but", "my", "second", "favorite", "is", "Exodus", "2:15"]
```

Now of course I could iterate through both "song" and "exod" and find Exodus with no problem, because it's not a book name that has more than one word. However, how would I be able to detect if "Song of Solomon" was in one of the items of the dict based on the tokenized string?

**If a solution for this specific method can't be found, would there be a way in which I could simplify the process?**

**NOTE**: I'm trying to find a way to "rebuild the string" to see if such string is in a list. In other words, I want to be able to know what the key of the list is if the rebuilt string is in such a list. (i.e. I should get "song" from ["my", "favorite", "verse", "is", "Song", "of", "Solomon", "1:2"])

**My solution was to no longer tokenize the string and use the string by itself in combination with @ezod's answer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finding All Songs in Non-tokenized Sentence

So, to find all the songs you iterate over the dictionary and accumulate the results:

```
def find_verses(book_dict, target_sentence):
    result = []
    for key, verse_list in book_dict.items():
        for verse in verse_list:
            if verse in target_sentence:
                result.append((key, verse))
    return result
```

EDIT 2: Remove token searching in token list because we would loose the phrases.

EDIT 3: Add code to find all verses

Comment: I'm trying to search using tokens in the tokenized list to see if any items in the dictionary contain such tokens (together).

Comment: @thevypr In that case you need to try various sized combinations of the tokens which would be inefficient if token list is large.

Comment: @thevypr Is iterating over the dictionary and searching for every value of each key not feasible?

Comment: Would a more sufficient method be possible? My main reason for the tokening is so I can detect all verses mentioned in a string.

Comment: @thevypr What do you mean by more sufficient?

Comment: RE: Iterating over the dictionary - Well, yes, the problem is that there can be overlap, for example many book names contain "1" or "2", which would result in me having multiple results for one book. I wouldn't know how to be able to make the search more specific from that point if iterating would be a possible method.

Comment: RE: Sufficient - Would there be a way to find multiple verses in a string and find the key respective to that book name without needing to tokenize and do bizarre rebuildings or iterate over the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171219/discussion-between-thevypr-and-eozd).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check if a list is a sublist of another list. You could check different segments of your bigger list and compare it to your tokenized query string.

```
query = ["Song", "of", "Salomon"]
text = ["my", "favorite", "verse", "is", "Song", "of", "Solomon", "1:2", "but", "my", "second", "favorite", "is", "Exodus", "2:15"]

is_sublist = any((query == text[i:i+len(query)] for i in range(0, len(text) - len(query))))
# is_sublist will be True
```

Comment: The text is the query, I'm not specifically targeting "Song of Solomon", I just need to be able to search in each dict item's list using a rebuilt string from the token, I believe. I'm just not sure how to do this or if an easier way is possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "rebuilt string from the token"

Comment: I need to either piece pieces of the tokenized list together and see if the result of that piecing is a value in any of the dict items' lists or find some alternative method of searching.